# Assert type is not any

Tags: typescript

How can I test/assert that a variable type is not "any" in Typescript?

I do not need a runtime check, it would be enough if the compiler gets an error to detect this:

```
function notAny(x: (rejects type any)) { ...}
let foo: any = 'value'

// tsc should throw an error here
notAny(foo)
```

The solution should be for only one check, not the whole project (like using `--noImplicitAny`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code below should work. The basic idea is that `any` is the only type that at the same time is the base type for `unknown` and the `{}` bottom (empty) type.

```js
type IsAny<T> =
  unknown extends T ? T extends {} ? T : never : never;

type NotAny<T> =
  T extends IsAny<T> ? never : T;

function notAny<T>(x: NotAny<T>) { }
let foo: any = 'value'

notAny(foo); // error as expected
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noImplicitAny=false&ssl=11&ssc=8&pln=11&pc=11#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgzgQQHYgDwBUB8UC8BYAKCigFckBrJAewHckoIAPYCJAEzinSgH4uHmrDlADeAX178AXFCQQAbhABOUGXMVKA3IUKhIUAHJVgyNFlyFi3Ji3ad4pjNj7rlqrtoKEAZmQDGwACWVPTUJihOABSMMkbhZpgAlKJQYoQANhDAUN5UVDIAhii4UADk8gXpJBClOgQA9PVQwHB%20UHAAFlQk6WzNHUq0nEUMSoMqHcoQhGGmkblUiUA)

Comment: `{}` isn't a bottom type; it's closer to a top type (and was the unofficial top type in TS before `unknown` was introduced).  Maybe you mean that `any` is the only type which is treated as both a top type (`T extends any` is true for all `T`) and a bottom type (`any extends T` is true for all `T`)?